# How to change the style of the border in the below xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml below and I want the **Border.Effect** property of the **Border** to be set to "**LightBlue**" when the Ischecked property of the radio button is set to true.
How can I achieve this in the xaml? (Need to find a generic way to do it, as I have a lot many control like this in my application)

Please find the xaml code below:

```
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <RadioButton Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsChecked="{Binding Count, Mode=TwoWay, Converter ={StaticResource IntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= 1}" GroupName="BCount"/>
                <Border Background="LightGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="300" Width="290" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Name="RadioLabel" Margin="15">
                            <Label.Content>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{x:Static local:Properties.Resources.SelectText}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Label.Content>
                        </Label>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Height="40" Margin="17,70,17,15" Source="SomeImage.png"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: The Border.Effect property is of type "Effect", you can't assign it a color. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change color of border, the right property is **BorderBrush**:

```
<Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" ...>
```

Use [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change this (or any) property when other property is in certain state.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this little example tested with kaxaml can help you

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
  <CheckBox x:Name="RB" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  <Border Width="290" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,15,0,0" Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
    <Border.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RB, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
              <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="LightBlue" ShadowDepth="0"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Name="RadioLabel" Margin="15">
        <Label.Content>
          <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Test"/>
          </TextBlock>
        </Label.Content>
      </Label>
      <Image Height="40" Margin="17,70,17,15" Source="SomeImage.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

hope that helps

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Suppose I want this style to be used for a lot of radio buttons with border, Is there some other way to do it(something like putting it in resource file) or do I need to write the inline style like this for everything?